# Form data not getting saved in django

Tags: django

Since django User model had only few fields in it, I made a custom model and used it's ModelForm to save data to User model and the custom model. The models.py is as shown below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
import datetime
class Post(models.Model):
    Author=models.ForeignKey(User)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=66)
    content=models.TextField()
    created_date=models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    published_date=models.DateField()
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date=datetime.datetime.now()
        self.save()



class UserDetails(models.Model): #the custom model
    uname=models.CharField(max_length=55)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=55)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=55)
    age=models.IntegerField()
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=13)
    email=models.EmailField()
    pword=models.CharField(max_length=55)
```

modelform :

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=UserDetails
        fields=['uname','pword','first_name','last_name','email','contact']
```

the views.py is like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import UserDetails
# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .forms import RegisterForm,LoginForm,PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=RegisterForm(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                uname=form.cleaned_data['uname']
                fname=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                pword=form.cleaned_data['pword']
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
                contact=form.cleaned_data['contact']
                lname=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                user=User.objects.create_user(uname,password=pword,email=email)
                user.last_name=lname
                user.save()
                #form.save()
                #stuff after registration
                message="registration done! login again"
                return render(request,'register.html',locals())
        except IntegrityError:
            message="username already exists!! try another"
    else:
        form=RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',locals())
```

The problem is that even if I make a fresh entry to the RegisterForm, the 'message' I get is, username already exists!! try another. The auth.User model is getting updated but UserDetails is not. What am I doing wrong? (spare me if this is a stupid question :) )

update: 1

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import UserDetails
# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .forms import RegisterForm,LoginForm,PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=RegisterForm(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                uname=form.cleaned_data['uname']
                fname=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                pword=form.cleaned_data['pword']
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
                contact=form.cleaned_data['contact']
                lname=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                if not User.objects.filter(username=uname,email=email).exists():
                    user=User.objects.create_user(uname,password=pword,email=email)
                    user.last_name=lname
                    user.save()
                message="registration done! login again"
                return render(request,'register.html',locals())
        except IntegrityError:
            message="username already exists!! try another"
    else:
        form=RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',locals())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Age was missing in model form Fields

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15510055)

Comment: @Denis I'm the author

Answer (score 1):

```
if form.is_valid():
    # save a UserDetails obj (data are automatically get from the form) to db.
    form.save()

    # Get data from form
    uname = form.cleaned_data['uname']
    fname = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    pword = form.cleaned_data['pword']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    contact = form.cleaned_data['contact']
    lname = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

    # Check if user already exists. If it doesn't, create it
    if not User.objects.filter(username=uname, email=email).exists():
        user=User.objects.create_user(uname, password=pword, email=email)

    #stuff after registration
    message = "registration done! login again"
    return render(request,'register.html',locals())
```

See more on the [`ModelForm`'s save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

However, I noticed that the `age` model field is `required`. So, the `save()` will complain. You should better make it as: `age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)` or define a default value like this `age = models.IntegerField(default=20)`. Although, defining a default age is awkward, better follow the `blank=True null=True` to allow empty `age`s.

Comment: I don't understand.. I already have a form.save() after if form.is_valid(). Shouldn't that work? The user.save() was used to save to update auth.User model.

Comment: That's exaclty what I mean. By doing `form.save()` the instance is saved directly in the db (with the form's data). After that, you are getting the form's data and create a new user. But this new user has been already created with `form.save()`.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. You have 2 separate models, `UserDetails` and `Post` which has a `ForeignKey` to `User`. My bad. Allow me to fix it, please.

Comment: Yes Sir, I have a UserDetails model and and a standard django.contrib.auth.User model what I tried to do was full the data from UserDetails modelform and use it to create a auth.User entry

Comment: Updated my answer. Maybe now ?

Comment: Totally unrelated but your `UserDetail` model should have a `OneToOneField` on `auth.User`.

Comment: @ajay: bruno is right. You should add an OneToOneField

Comment: Added the suggested change in update 1. No change @nik_m.

Comment: Thank you @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: The integrityerror was caused by the age field. It was missing in the model field list thankyou

Comment: @AJAYAJITH may you learn something from this: when you catch an exception, always log the full exception message and never assume you really know what happens. And always keep your try/except blocks as small as possible...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i will keep that in mind. Thank you

Comment: Glad we could help. Thank you!